# c# add progress bar into textBox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, progress-bar

how can i do for add an progressBar into textBox area? ( something like safari browser do on its address bar ) ? Any tutorial?
Thx

Comment: why the c++ tag? Is this question related to C++ somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle a TextBox's `PaintBackground` event and draw a colored rectangle of appropriate width.

Comment: There is some example?or tutorials?

Comment: Not that I know of off-hand.  You will need to expend actual effort and write actual code.  (You can also try Googling it)

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a `ProgressBar` over your `TextBox`, and modify it's `visible` at runtime?

Comment: That will hide the textbox's text.

Comment: you still can change textbox to the front when user edit/select